# Get CostModel stats/estimates in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there an easy way to get stats/estimates like time estimate, total count or memory estimate of input/output tensors in TensorFlow e.g through the python API?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to to is to enable the collection of the cost model:

```
# Collect and aggregate statistics every 50 iterations
options = tf.GraphOptions(build_cost_model=50)
cfg = tf.ConfigProto(graph_options=options)
sess = tf.Session(config=cfg)
```

You can then generate an updated version of the cost model as follow:

```
metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
# This is optional, but will generally give you more accurate statistics,
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)

for step in xrange(0, 1000):
  _ = sess.run([train_op], options=run_options, run_metadata=metadata)

  if len(metadata.cost_graph.node) > 0:
    print ("HERE IS THE COST GRAPH " + str(metadata.cost_graph))
```

Comment: When I do this I get: TypeError: run() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options' (but I am using InteractiveSession)