# TensorFlow: Cost graph is empty in RunMetadata

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215432/get-costmodel-stats-estimates-in-tensorflow) to get cost model estimates from TensorFlow. However, when I print the resulting `metadata.cost_graph`, the output is empty. Is there anything else I need to do?

I want to see the cost estimates from TensorFlow's cost model and how it maps to the devices. Is there any other way I can accomplish this?

Here's the full program:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Create random large matrix
A = np.random.rand(10000, 10000).astype('float32')
B = np.random.rand(10000, 10000).astype('float32')

with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10000, 10000])
    b = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [10000, 10000])

with tf.device('gpu:0'):
    mul = tf.matmul(a, b)

metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
ops = tf.GraphOptions(build_cost_model=5)

with tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True,
    graph_options=ops)) as sess:
    # Run the op.
    for _ in xrange(20):
         sess.run([mul], feed_dict={a:A, b:B}, options=run_options,
            run_metadata=metadata)
         print ("Cost graph " + str(metadata.cost_graph))
```

Comment: Maybe you are wrong in this line `with tf.device('gpu:0'):`. It needs a / ahead of gpu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `tf.GraphOptions.build_cost_model` option is [defined](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9d66dae6fc5d1b964a03498ddabb97a78a999015/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L111) as being the number of steps that will run before a cost model is produced. From the definition:

```
// The number of steps to run before returning a cost model detailing
// the memory usage and performance of each node of the graph. 0 means
// no cost model.
int64 build_cost_model = 4;
```

Therefore, to see a cost model, you must run the graph 50 times with `build_cost_model=50`. For better performance, I'd recommend only passing `run_options` on the 50th call (otherwise TensorFlow will produce and discard a large amount of metadata).

Comment: I tried running it a few hundred times, but the graph is empty at the 100th, 150th, 200th, etc calls. Is this the normal behavior? It does show up in the 50th loop though. Thanks.

Comment: It's possible I made an off-by-one error, but it should be periodic. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9d66dae6fc5d1b964a03498ddabb97a78a999015/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc#L451), which looks like it ought to set `update_costs` (and hence return a cost graph) every 50 steps.

Comment: Okay I updated the `build_cost_model=5` and runs the graph 20 times like this: `for _ in range(20): sess.run(..., options=run_options,...)`. Did I do it correctly?

Comment: That sounds correct. How many cost graphs did you see in the resulting `tf.RunMetadata` objects? (I'd expect 4 or 5, assuming you passed the same `tf.RunOptions` to every call. If not, that sounds like a bug.)

Comment: One. I'd expect it to be periodic as you said too, but it only shows up in the 5th iteration (the first time, and not again). Can you run my script and see if you can reproduce? It should be self-contained.